# What kind of sentence constituent is "a little"?

Tags: parts-of-speech

> Tell me ***a little*** about yourself.

I have got two explanations of "a little":

> 1. "a little" functions as a ***pronoun.*** It means ***"something" or "a few things"***
> 2. "a little" serves as ***an adverb of degree***, which ***modifies the verb "tell"***. It means that you don't have to tell me all about yourself,
>      just tell me partly about yourself.

I don't know which one is correct.

Answer (score 1):

For the example you provided, the first explanation is the most fitting.

'A little' may be swapped with 'something' and not lose its meaning:

> Tell me **a little** about yourself.
>
> Tell me **something** about yourself.

That is because 'a little' is the **direct object** of the verb 'tell'.

Here are some examples of 'a little' being used as an adverb:

> Move that chair **a little.**
>
> Live **a little,** love a lot.