# "in 60 seconds or less" or "in 60 seconds or fewer"?

Tags: word-choice, countability

Tell me please which sentence is correct.

> I want you to articulate your ideas in 60 seconds or **less**.
>
> I want you to articulate your ideas in 60 seconds or **fewer**.

The word second is a countable noun, so theoretically it should be *60 second or fewer*, but what I heard English native speakers say is *60 seconds or less*.

Comment: Related: https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/68353/9161 This question on ELU might be helpful as well [Less vs. Fewer](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/495/80039)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

"60 seconds" is the amount of time, so by saying "60 seconds or less" you basically say "in less amount of time than 60 seconds."

According to [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/grammar/less-or-fewer), less is also used with numbers when they are on their own and with expressions of measurement or time, e.g.:

> - His weight fell from 18 stone to less than 12.
> - Their marriage lasted less than two years.
> - Heath Square is less than four miles away from Dublin city centre.

From [an answer on English Language and Usage SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/189313/less-and-fewer-in-english):

> The general principle here is that less should be used when describing
>   a continuous quantity and fewer should be used for a discrete
>   quantity. This is not the same as countable v non-countable.
>
> Time is a continuous quantity, so "5 minutes or less" is correct.
>
> A purchase is a discrete quantity, so "10 items or fewer" is correct.

Comment: Note that you *can* make time a discrete quantity. *Do you need as many as 60 seconds to articulate your ideas, or can you do so with fewer?* It comes down to our interpretation. Here, *as many as*  and *with* imply a discrete count of individual units, making *fewer* appropriate.)

Comment: @JasonBassford I would disagree with that example. IMO it should be "Do you need as *long* as 60 seconds to articulate your ideas, or can you do so in *less* [time]?" or "... in a shorter time".

Comment: I think this answer makes sense as an explanation of proper grammar. However, you should also be aware that, in modern colloquial usage, more and more people tend to use "less" exclusively. In many cases, "fewer" will sound formal or stilted to many people, even when technically correct. See for example: https://www.npr.org/2014/12/06/368712564/fewer-or-less-the-express-lane-language-debate

Comment: @alephzero You're missing my point. You're *choosing* to make it an uncountable amount; I'm deliberately choosing to make it countable. Your personal opinion may be that one *sounds* better; but, in terms of syntax, it can certainly be made countable, so long as the right phrasing and wording is used.

Comment: Would your answer change if time were not continuous? It's an open problem in physics.

Comment: @JasonBassford, I think you should make your comments into a new answer. It's a good point.

Comment: @Joshua The answer would only change if you’re using Planck units rather than seconds to measure the time. Something whose parts are small enough that it’s effectively continuous is continuous. You have less flour not fewer flour, even though flour is technically composed of discrete units that could in principle be counted.

Comment: @GlennWillen OP should also be aware that there are still plenty of people around who will think less of you if you tell them that you got less socks out of the dryer than you put into it.

Comment: @Joshua That's not something I would consider relevant in this case.

Comment: Good answer.  Though it's worth noting that the ‘less’/‘fewer’ distinction seems to be less and less observed these days, with ‘less’ being used for discrete quantities as well as continuous ones.  (I suspect that the word ‘fewer’ will eventually fall out of use.)

Comment: @JasonBassford I'm not sure that makes much sense; a minute isn't inherently a collection of 60 discrete seconds, it's a single block of continuous time that happens to "measure" 60 seconds in duration. Just like a liter of water isn't a collection of 1000 discrete ml. Of course nobody will misunderstand you if you use "60 seconds or fewer", but I think "60 seconds or less" is correct.

Comment: @BradC Of course it *can* be considered a collection of discrete seconds. If it couldn't, *I'm going to add another second to the clock* would make no sense. But it does. You can easily add and remove single seconds from a clock or timer. Whether you view a minute as a bulk amount or an additive amount is based entirely on your perspective.