# Less than versus fewer than

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammaticality, comparative-constructions

**I  completed  my  Doctoral  Degree  in less than  four  years.**

**I  completed  my  Doctoral Degree  in  fewer  than  four  years.**

Are  both the  sentences  correct  and  mean  the  same  thing  or one  of  them  wrong?

I know  that  less is  used  for  uncountable  singular  nouns  and  fewer  is  used  for  countable  plural  nouns.

Comment: Related: [Confusion about 'less' and 'fewer' in sentences with countable/uncountable nouns](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/68353/9161)

Answer (score 1):

> I completed my Doctoral Degree in **less** than four years.
>
> I completed my Doctoral Degree in **fewer** than four years.

Both are grammatically correct. However, using "fewer" here is quite unlikely.

Since you already now that "less" is for *uncountable* nouns and "fewer" is for *countable* nouns, it should be simple to see how those can modify the word "year".

When "less" is used, the time to complete the Doctoral can be anywhere between 0 and 4 years, like 3 years + 6 months, which is 3.5 years.

When "fewer" is used, it means the number of years should be an *integer* or *whole number*. Here, it can be 0, 1, 2 or 3 years. "3 years and 6 months" is 3.5 years, which isn't an integer number of years, and should go with "less" instead of "fewer".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, both are correct although the former is far more likely.

**In less than four years** means than in less than this amount of time.

**In fewer than four years**, which is much less common, means in not as many years.

It comes down to whether you are regarding the time involved as a continuum or as individual years. The same principle applies where other measures such as weights or volumes are concerned.

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=less+than+four+years%2Cfewer+than+four+years

Comment: *"It comes down to whether you are regarding the time involved as a **continuum** or as **individual years.**"* - I think you forgot to identify which to use (i.e., less or fewer) when regarding time as "continuum" or "individual years", unless by "amount of time" you mean "continuum".