# Which of these: "I only have few left" or "I only have a few left"

Tags: sentence-construction

So, my son is being challenged by his teacher with the following exercise:

I need cosmetics from Avon because I only have *much / a little / few* left.

Jac's version:  "I only have a little left"

While the "other" version is "I only have few left"

So, just thought I would post this to see how it goes...

Comment: Check out this overview of little/few: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/31717/difference-between-little-few-a-little-and-a-few

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jac's version, "I only have a little left", is correct.

"only" makes "a little" sound negative (meaning that the person is short of cosmetics).

"a few" (not *few*) would also be possible, but this would suggest a variety of cosmetics, not cosmetics in general as is the case with "a little".

Curiously, "only" requires those pronouns to be preceded by "a", which can only be omitted if "only" is left out:

- I **only** have **a little** left.
- I have **little** left.
- I **only** have **a few** left.
- I have **few** left.

We can of course also say:

- I have **a little** left.
- I have **a few** left.

but these will not have the restrictive meaning that is intended.

Comment: Yes, I agree, my excuse (feeble) is that I have just completed 140 exams for students using Excel and my brain is fried...