# The problem of zero article

Tags: articles, zero-article

I don’t understand when I should use zero article.

Can you explain me usage of article in these sentences:
1. They have little experience.
2. You can have a little rest.

I think in both cases we are talking about abstractions.
Please help me.

Comment: Suprisingly, the duplicate questions are getting more upvotes than the original questions.The way of the users is really mysterious

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though it seems to be a simple question it is some what lengthy to answer.

Little is some (what)  lesser in degree to a little.

Little may mean not much and a little may mean some (what). some times the meaning may  be the same.

> **They have little experience** may mean:

They do not have much experience

> **You can have a little rest**.

The sentence may mean you can have some rest.

For detailed information the link given below helps you much.

[Difference between “little”, “few”, “a little” and “a few”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/31717/difference-between-little-few-a-little-and-a-few)