# BrE. Why do these expressions little/very little; few/very few exist if they are the same?

Tags: grammar, british-english

I can’t understand these words.
“ he has got little money” and “ he has got VERY LITTLE money”; “ I have got few friends” and “I have got VERY FEW friends”.

Comment: Have you done any research?

Comment: _A little_ = a small amount (seen in a positive way). _[Very] little_ = only a small amount (seen in a negative way). _Few_ works similarly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between “little”, “few”, “a little” and “a few”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/31717/difference-between-little-few-a-little-and-a-few)

Comment: Following from what Kate says, “He has got a little money” means that he has *enough* money for what is being discussed. But the other two mean that he probably does *not* have enough money.

Comment: I have very little patience even when I try to have a little patience. And I do not believe you. Especially, when someone tells me something is British English when it isn't. None of your questions are "British English". Mind how you go, mate. [That is BrE, by the way].

Comment: How can you say these expressions are British English if you don't know them? That's a logical impossibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Very X* is an intensifier; X is usually an adjective or adverb.  It means the meaning of X is stronger than normal, expected, or compared to others.  There is no exact or fixed level of intensity; it's relative to common, assumed, or previously communicated information or experiences between speaker/writer and reader/listener.

*Very* can modify itself, so you can say *very very little*, or *very very very little*, for example.

*Very* is also a word that's frequently thrown into conversation for exaggeration purposes in order to make it more interesting or attention-grabbing, and can be overused, particularly by excitable or nervous people.

Comment: Why are you not saying that this is not BrE? This posters keeps posting under the BrE title, and he has not been right,once. Lemme tell'ya, he prolly ain't got no friends. [smile]

Comment: Is this not true for BrE as well?  If not let me know and I'll delete if  totally inapplicable.