# What is the real meaning of "quite a little number of ..."?

Tags: modifiers

**quite a few** - phrase used with countable nouns

*quite a few apples -> many apples*

**quite a little** - phrase used with uncountable nouns

*quite a little money -> much money*

but what about

*quite a little number of apples.* -> what does this mean?

number is countable, so it violates the usage of "quite a little", but at the same time, I feel like it means quite little (very small) so -> a very small number of apples.

I can say "quite a **small** number of apples" and have confidence it means "very few apples," but because "quite a little" is a British English idiom, I am not sure which is the correct meaning.

Comment: "quite a little number of apples" Where did you find this sentence? who used it? Can you link the source? In the mean time try having a look at this https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/31717/difference-between-little-few-a-little-and-a-few.

Comment: @Brad I made the phrase. It didn't sound overtly wrong, but at the same time I was having trouble determining if it was proper English, and if so, did it mean what I thought it meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

quite a little number of apples. -> what does this mean?

As the source has not been quoted I would suggest that the sentence in this case is incorrect. Quite a little NUMBER being incorrect. This particular idiom has several variations (see below) If we had wished to use the word  number. Then a different variation of the idiom would have been used, in fact the more commonly quoted variation, "quite a number".

> We are not finished; ***quite a little*** is left to do.

> There are ***quite a number*** of things involved in this question.

However with apples I would suggest not quite a little or even quite a number but

> There are ***quite a lot*** of bad apples

---

**quite a little**

**Idiom(s)**: quite a bit AND quite a few; quite a little; quite a lot; quite a number Ref [Idioms](https://www.proverbmeaning.com/en/idiom/quite+a+little)

> All of which mean "***a considerable amount***"

---

> quite a little:
> in British English:
> a considerable amount

Ref [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/quite-a-little)

Comment: I'll accept that the phrase is simply an incorrect amalgamation of several idioms ("a number of", and "quite a little." Thanks for the second opinion.

Comment: @Exec your welcome.